# sum of independent Rayleigh random variables

Tags: stochastic-processes, random

How do I find the probability density distribution (pdf) of the sum of independent Rayleigh random variables (whose probability density functions are known)? where is the reference?
Could anybody please possibly paste the original convolution integral (definition) which expresses the pdf of the sum of independent Rayleigh random variables with different scale parameters? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a name for it.  For example, according to Maple the sum of two independent Rayleigh random variables with the same scale parameter $b$ has PDF
$$ f(z) = \dfrac{z}{2b^2} e^{-z^2/(2b^2)} + \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi} z^2}{4b^3} \text{erf}\left(\frac{z}{2b}\right) e^{-z^2/(4b^2)} - \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2b} \text{erf}\left(\frac{z}{2b}\right) e^{-z^2/(4b^2)}$$

EDIT: if the scale parameters are $b_1$ and $b_2$, Maple gets
$$\eqalign{\sqrt {\pi/2}{{\rm e}^{-1/2\,{\frac {{z}^{2}}{{b_{{1}}}^{2}+{b_{{2}}}
^{2}}}}}
{{\rm erf}\left(1/2\,{\frac {\sqrt {2}b_{{2}}z}{b_{{1}}\sqrt {{b_{{1}}}^{2}+{b_{{2}}}^{2}}}}\right)}
 \left( {z}^{2}-{b_{{1}}}^{2}-{b_{{2}}}^{2} \right) b_{{2}}b_{{1}}
 \left( {b_{{1}}}^{2}+{b_{{2}}}^{2} \right) ^{-5/2}\cr+
\sqrt {\pi/2}{{\rm e}^{-1/2\,{\frac {{z}^{2}}{{b_{{1}}}^{2}+{b_{{2}}}^{2}}
}}}
{{\rm erf}\left(1/2\,{\frac {z\sqrt {2}b_{{1}}}{b_{{2}}\sqrt {{b_{{1}}}^{2}+{b_{{2}}}^{2}}}}\right)}
 \left( {z}^{2}-{b_{{1}}}^{2}-{b_{{2}}}^{2} \right) b_{{2}}b_{{1}}
 \left( {b_{{1}}}^{2}+{b_{{2}}}^{2} \right) ^{-5/2}\cr+z{b_{{
1}}}^{2}{{\rm e}^{-1/2\,{\frac {{z}^{2}}{{b_{{1}}}^{2}}}}} \left( {b_{
{1}}}^{2}+{b_{{2}}}^{2} \right) ^{-2}+{{\rm e}^{-1/2\,{\frac {{z}^{2}}
{{b_{{2}}}^{2}}}}}z{b_{{2}}}^{2} \left( {b_{{1}}}^{2}+{b_{{2}}}^{2}
 \right) ^{-2}\cr}
$$

Comment: It appears right. if b1^2+b2^2=1, the pdf could be simplified. It seems that it is not easy to determine the integral (between 0 and infinity). Could you please possibly paste the original convolution integral which leads to such result.

Comment: Actually I didn't do an integral, just (in Maple's Statistics package) defined $X$ and $Y$ as random variables with the appropriate distributions and asked for the PDF of $X+Y$.

Comment: Desperately, the convolution integral which leads to the Robert's formula via Maple is sought. Anybody can provide it? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: $$\int_0^z \dfrac{t(z-t)}{b_1^2 b_2^2} \exp\left(-\dfrac{t^2}{2b_1^2} - \dfrac{(z-t)^2}{2b_2^2}\right)\; dt$$

Comment: Wonderful. Many thanks for your post, Prof. Robert. Would you please possibly expalin a litte more about the upper limit being the argument (z) not being the infinity. Usually, the upper limit of the convolution integral for the pdf of the sum of independent random varaibles is the variable "infinity", am I right? Why here it is the argument (z) for the Rayleigh random variable? Is it beacuse the fact that the difference (z-t) is neagive is not allowed for the Rayleigh distribution? I am not so sure about this. Looking forward to hearing from you. Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: Another question,  Prof. Robert. Can the MAPLE statistics software integrate between 0 to the infinity with respect to z the PDF of X+Y with different scale parameters? What is the final integration result? One or what else? Looking forward to hearing from you. Sorry to bother you so much. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Yes, in principle the convolution is an integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, but the integrand is only nonzero from $0$ to $z$.

Comment: Hi, Prof. Robert. It seems that the normalization of the convolution integral is required in general as one can not ensure that the area under the pdf curve is unity, unless for certain special cases.

Comment: No.  If $f$ and $g$ are absolutely integrable then $\int_{-\infty}^\infty (f \star g)(x)\ dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) g(x-t)\ dt dx = \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ dx\right) \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\ dx\right)$.

Comment: Prof. Israel, your proof is absolutely right and easy to be understandable. You are awesome. Keep in touch. If I encounter any difficult mathematical problems, I shall definitely consult you for a wonderful solution. Great salute to you, Prof. Israel. Wish you all the best. Have a good day.

Comment: Prof. Israel, how do you think the software MAPLE? It seems excellent. I do not have the MAPLE software. I may need to purchase one copy. Do you have any recommendations on MAPLE editions?