# Recursive convolution of a distribution with itself

Tags: probability-distributions, convolution

Consider a distribution $f(t)$. I can take the convolution of this with itself as
$$(f * f) = \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} f(\tau)f(t-\tau) \ d\tau$$
If we then do a second stage of convolution as 
$$((f * f) * f) = \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} (f * f)(\tau)f(t-\tau) \ d\tau$$

To make this more compact I relabel $(f * f)$ as $F_{N=1} = (f * f)$, as the convolution iteration cycle as been done once. I would therefore relabel $((f * f) * f)$ as $F_{N=2} = ((f * f) * f)$ and so on.

Writing this as a general form 
$$F_{N} = \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} F_{N-1}(\tau) f(t - \tau) \ d\tau$$

**Is it possible to solve such an integral explicitly?**

What I am trying to show is that as $N\rightarrow \infty$ I should recover the Gaussian distribution as per the central limit theorem.

Specifically I want to show this for when my $f(x)$ distribution is the Rayleigh distribution:
$$f(x) = \frac{x}{\sigma^{2}} e^{-x^{2}/\left(2 \sigma^{2} \right)}$$

I would ideally like to derive a distribution where I have a two parameter distribution $R(\sigma, N)$ where
$$RR(\sigma, N) \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} = G(x,\sigma)$$
$G(x,\sigma)$ being the Gaussian distribution.

Comment: So, you are looking for the pdf of the sum of $n$ iid random variables following a same Rayleigh distribution ? But even when $n=2$ it is awfully complicated (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/720830)

Comment: Exactly so, and, oh dear....